# pandas MultiIndex assign multiple columns

Tags: pandas, multi-index

I have created a dataframe with a MultiIndex like below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
column_index= [np.array(['OPEN','OPEN','CLOSE','CLOSE']),np.array(['IBM','AAPL','IBM','AAPL'])]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]])),index=['20190101','20190102','20190103'],columns=column_index)
```

The result is like this:

```
          OPEN          CLOSE
          IBM   AAPL    IBM AAPL
20190101    1    4      7   10
20190102    2    5      8   11
20190103    3    6      9   12
```

Now I'd like to create a new set of columns by doing something like:

```
df['RTN'] = df.CLOSE / df.OPEN
```

To get:

```
            OPEN      CLOSE       RTN
            IBM AAPL  IBM   AAPL  IBM   AAPL
20190101    1   4     7     10    7.0   2.5
20190102    2   5     8     11    4.0   2.2
20190103    3   6     9     12    3.0   2.0
```

That does not work.  The nicest way I've been able to do this is like so:

```
rtn = df.CLOSE / df.OPEN
rtn = pd.concat([rtn],keys=['RTN'],axis=1)
df = pd.concat([df,rtn],axis=1)
```

Is there a way to do this as an assignment without the other steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to `rename` the columns prior to the operations. Then it's a simple concat:

```
u = df.loc[:, ['CLOSE']].rename(columns={'CLOSE': 'RTN'}, level=0).divide(
        df.loc[:, ['OPEN']].rename(columns={'OPEN': 'RTN'}, level=0))
                   # [] DataFrame selection keeps MultiIndex

pd.concat([df, u], axis=1)
```

---

Alternatively, you can `stack` + `eval` + `unstack`. It's concise, but perhaps not super performant for large datasets.

```
df.stack().eval('RTN = CLOSE/OPEN').unstack()
#df.stack().assign(RTN = lambda x: x.CLOSE/x.OPEN).unstack()
```

Without `eval`:

```
df.stack().assign(RTN = lambda x: x.CLOSE/x.OPEN).unstack()

#or 

df = df.stack()
df['RTN'] = df.CLOSE/df.OPEN
df = df.unstack()
```

---

Output in all cases:

```
         OPEN      CLOSE       RTN     
          IBM AAPL   IBM AAPL  IBM AAPL
20190101    1    4     7   10  7.0  2.5
20190102    2    5     8   11  4.0  2.2
20190103    3    6     9   12  3.0  2.0
```